# Maximum coefficient of friction between nylon and polyethylene

Tags: polymers

For a research project I found out last minute that I need the coefficient of friction between nylon and Ultra-high-molecular-weight polyethylene. After hours of scouring google nothing useful turned up.

Since I actually need the maximum and not the precise value, I came here to ask what that could possibly be and if there is any literature on that. Basically I need to find out what the maximum friction could be, caused by a Dyneema (polyethylene) rope on a plastic nylon pulley.

I was hoping there is some sort of "rule" what the maximum coefficient of friction could be for 2 smooth plastic surfaces.